# submitting the form after successful paypal money transaction using php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, transactions, paypal

I've made a form. Currently this form does the following operations:

1. customer fills up the form (creates an order)
2. clicks on "Submit" button
3. all form entries are entered into a database.

I'd like to change it to do the following operations:

1. customer fills up the form
2. in the end of the form there is a text box showing much this order will cost him.
3. clicks on "Submit" button (if accepts the price)
4. redirected to paypal
5. if the payment is successful -> all form entries are entered into a database. Else -> echo "transaction failed".

Here is what I've done so far:

**"form.php" contents**

```
<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body>
<form action="php-form-processor.php" method="post">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="5" width = "500">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" width="160">Choose an Item:</td>
            <td align="left">
            <select name="formItem" value="<?=$varItem;?>" class="input_full" >
                <option value="1">Cheese</option>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#D0E8F5">
            <td align="right" >Item count:</td>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="text" name="formItemCount" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varItemCount = 1;?>"  class="input_full" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" align = "center" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form></body></html>
```

**"php-form-processor.php" contents**

```
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $varItem = $_POST['formItem'];
    $varItemCount = $_POST['formItemCount'];

    //database stuff
    $username = "...";
    $password = "...";
    $hostname = "..."; 
 // connect and add to the database varItem and varItemCount
    mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close($dbhandle);
}
?>
```

The form is much bigger but i've simplified the stackoverflow's version of it. The price of an order must change according to "varItem" and "varItemCount" value. Basically I want to add "Pay with PayPal" option before writing an order into the database.
P.S. I've already registered paypal Sandbox account and added "Buyer" and a "Seller".

what should I do next?

**EDIT: ok, so here is a small guide how to solve the problem.** Here are some advises:

- first, download paypal IPN listener wrapper: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN
- then register SandBox account plus 1 buyer and 1 seller acc
- login as a seller and create a form (with non-hosted button!)
- place the form into your page and parse the ID or any other necessary information via "custom" input (some helpful advises can be found here: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Creating-a-Paypal-IPN-System-in-PHP-Part-Two/)
- now place redirect to this page after Form submit
- don't forget to enable IPN at paypal Seller account and enter IPNlistener link into a necessary address field
- submit a paypal form and wait for response on listener
- done

Whole proccess looks like this:

1. customer fills up the form
2. after submitting the form - all entries are written into the database + ID  + 1 additional field called "payed" which represents: 1 - if customer payed for an order and 0 - if not
3. use header("Location: URL") to redirect from Form_Processing to Paypal_Form
4. use the "session" to write order ID into a session or use POST message
5. submit the PaypalForm and use "custom" field as a carier for our order ID
6. set up the listener to update the database as following: if transaction was successful -> update the database column "payed" to 1 (done). Use the ID from "custom" field to select needed order i.e.:

$sql = "UPDATE paypal_test SET payed = '1' WHERE id = '".$_POST['custom']."'";

Now we have a database with completed and non-completed forms. Additionaly you can write a logic which will remove "old" uncompleted orders. For this reason you can create additional column called "date" and then compare: if (current_date.days - old_date.days > 7) -> remove from DB. That's it!

Comment: What is your actual question? It seems to me you still need confirmation from Paypal on this transaction (your step 5). Are you using the IPN mechanism for this?

Comment: Make sure you are checking the amount the person(s) paid - you can modify the input POST variables to PayPal with some client hacking so someone could pay $1 for a $100 item and unless you check it they could get away with it. PayPal will respond with the amount if I remember correctly. Also ensure this is the correct type of transaction (I think "Web Payment Accept" but there is loads of different ones like "eCheque" which do not represent a completed transaction - the IPN sends all notifications, including refunds)

Comment: oops not enough time to edit the comment so I'll create a new one soon

Comment: @williamvicary Thank you for suggestion regarding price check.. I'll create a database column which will contain the price that customer has to pay.. If the response I receive from the paypal has a different sum of money -> database won't be updated. If there are some other methods/ideas to improve the security I'll gladly hear them out! Also, regarding "transaction type" I don't fully understand how "eCheque" is any worse than "Web Payment Accept" and how can I ensure that customer won't use the "bad" method? Unless paypal has that option ofc.

Comment: Paypal doesn't have that option, an eCheque takes time to clear and afaik can be cancelled by the payee. I suggest you read the variable docs https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNReference#id08CTB0S055Z it was a few years ago and things might have changed.

Comment: very good explanation and thank you it has helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not accept what the PayPal post back is giving you, it's a sloppy way of checking the authentication of the user and expects the user to click the "go back to website" button. Instead use the IPN (https://www.paypal.com/ipn/) and make sure you post the response back to PayPal for verification.

Checkout this PHP example from PayPal: https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation

Comment: thank you! your IPN suggestion was helpful. Look at "edit" to see how i solved the problem in the end. (if you want to ofc) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you pretty much already described what you need to do:

- 1st: make an onChange javascript, that sums up the value and posts it at the place you want;
- 2nd: do a php check of the values after submit ( make sure to also check for injection issues );
- 3rd: redirect to paypal and wait for the answer;
- 4th: according to paypals answer echo out the result;

PS: I hope you are not waiting for someone to actually rewrite the whole script for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tat late to the party....but in 2021 try this..

If you want to use a custom form in combination with paypals Smart Payment Buttons (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) then you could try this approach. That works for me and you also don't need IPN (below approach is most current and much faster).

On your frontend use this (w/ this you can send your form data to your server):
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

On you backend use this (I put create & capture code in one file):
To create the order:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/
To capture the order:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/
To set it up:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/

Now you can write form data to your db after paypal approved the order.

Gave similar answer here
[How to submit data for the address and payment details after PayPal payment is made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129612/how-to-submit-data-for-the-address-and-payment-details-after-paypal-payment-is-m/67397322#67397322)